# SQL. How to combine two records with the same ID into one line based on value's in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

SQL Server 2012: how to combine two records with the same ID (TransportOrder) into one line based on value's in a column (PalletType)?

Example: order 678 has two lines with 1 europallet en 3 BetweenEuropallet. So de order takes only 1 TransportEuropalletPlace.

The output should be in the case of order 678, one line, telling there is total 4 europallets (sum 1 + 3 from two lines) and 1 TransportEuropalletPlace (SUM 1 + 0)

How to achieve this with SQL query?

Original output:

```
TransportOrder   PalletType            Quantity    TransportEuropalletPlace
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      123        Minipallet               1                0.5
      345        Europallet               1                1
      678        Europallet               1                1
      678        BetweenEuropallet        3                0
      900        Europallet               2                2
```

Output needed for order 678:

```
TransportOrder   PalletType    Quantity    TransportEuropalletPlace 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     123         Minipallet       1              0.5 
     345         Europallet       1              1 
     678         Europallet       4              1 
     900         Europallet       2              2
```

Comment: Why does the combined line have `Europallet` instead of `BetweenEuropallet` in the `PalletType` column? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: As logistic unit, you start with Europallet, put pruduct boxes on it, then put above of boxes a new Europallet. This Europallet abobe we call "BetweenEuropallet". In this manner a tranposrt unit with products is builded. Onder 1 Europallet and above so-called BetweenPallets (between the doses with the products).So we have to say, how much such Europalets this transport unit has. Lets say in my example 4 Europallets total, but it takes only one Europallet place in a truck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should group by the column `TransportOrder`, as in:

```
select
  transportorder,
  max(pallettype) as pallettype,
  sum(quantity) as quantity,
  sum(transporteuropalletplace) as transporteuropalletplace
from my_table
group by transportorder
```

Comment: Update: in my case, I  should choose MIN(pallettype) as pallettype in order to get in the combined line Europallet instead of BetweenEuropallet in the PalletType column. Nice work of Min(Max) function on a string data type. With this example I found a solution in my query. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
SELECT
    TransportOrder,
    SUM(ISNULL(Europallet,0) + ISNULL(BetweenEuropallet, 0)) as 'Pallets'
FROM Table_Name
GROUP BY TransportOrder
```

Comment: I think this query won't combine both lines `678` since they have a different `PalletType`.